# Is there any algorithm for converting 2D video into 3D video?

Tags: algorithm, video, 3d, 2d, translation

Is there any algorithm for converting 2D video into 3D video (for viewing using glasses)?

(A-la turning Avatar into Avatar for an [IMAX 3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAX#IMAX_3D) experience.) Or at least turn it into video prepared for feeling some 3D viewing using it a-la:

[image]
<sub>(source: [3dglassesonline.com](http://www.3dglassesonline.com/how-do-3d-glasses-work/3-d-glasses-traditional.gif))</sub>

or

[image]
<sub>(source: [3dglassesonline.com](http://www.3dglassesonline.com/how-do-3d-glasses-work/3-d-glasses-polarization-new.gif))</sub>

Comment: may be using normals to create something like 3d experience?

Comment: it looks like the idea of auto-color methods for black & white movies of old days. it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably understand the difference between polarizing glasses and red/blue glasses. The red/blue glasses 3D effect is simple to do. You simply need to take a picture about a couple of inches apart (kind of like how are eyes are laid out) and superimpose each image over the other. There is a tutorial on how to do this in *[Making Anaglyph Images in Adobe Photoshop](http://designinstruct.com/photography/3d-anaglyph-photoshop/)*.

As for the polarizing glasses effect, this is a little harder. If you go to a movie theatre and watch a 3D movie with polarizing glasses, you are seeing true 3D. It works by having has two projectors. One projector is projecting the movie in one type of polarization and the second projector is projecting the movie at the other type of polarization. The images are overlaid right on top of each other so if you're wearing your 3D polarizing glasses, it appears in 3D.

This can't be done as easily with a TV or computer monitor. Your TV or monitor would have to project two images simultaneously. Due to the popularity of 3D now though, there are 3D TVs and monitors appearing on the market that do not project two images, but display 3D. Here's how they work:

A normal computer screen or TV refreshes at a frequency of 60 Hz. This means 60 times in one second, the image you see is being refreshed. Because this is so fast, the human eye doesn't see flicker. 3D TVs and monitors refresh at 120 Hz. The polarizing images are interchanges at a rate of 120 times per second, but since there are two, it appears at 60 times a second, which is what produces the 3D effect.

I hope this helps you understand a little.

To answer your question, yes, you can create 3D videos, but you would need a 3D monitor and 3D TV to watch it.

Comment: This is answering a different question - how are 3D movies made.  The question asked was how to train a computer to convert an existing 2d film into 3d by interpreting the same type of visual cues that humans use to estimate depth.

Answer (score 15):

Well, Stanford does have [an algorithm for converting 2D *photos* into 3D models](http://make3d.cs.cornell.edu/). My guess is that with movies it should be even easier, because then you have several photos instead of just one, so you can extract much more information about depth by comparing neighboring frames.

Arguably, the results will never be quite as good as when you just render/shoot the movie in 3D to begin with.

Comment: Similar research can be found e.g. here: http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~thormae/paper/Siggraph08_orthoimage.pdf

Answer (score 4):

No - 3D video require that extra information (depth) be present that simply isn't contained in 2D video.

If you have a 2D rendering of a sceene (for example in Toy Story) then its quite easy to produce a 3D film - you just change the viewing angle of the sceene and re-render.

Comment: s/2D rendering/3D scene description/

Comment: Well, humans can judge depth when they look at a 2D movie, so the information *is* there. It's just very hard to write an algorithm that can extract it.

Answer (score 4):

It cannot work in general for a very simple reason: Suppose you have a scene with a window in a wall showing a beach, and beside that, you have a photograph showing a window in a wall showing a beach. How can the algorithm differentiate between the two? How can you detect what is reality with depth and what is just a flat photograph?

Comment: Your example is a perfect one.  Easily explains why this can never really work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Should the algorithm somehow understand the scene content and extrapolate depth information from that? Remember that 3D video needs depth information. Otherwise there is no way of knowing how much to offset the two frame parts.

You could probably try it by assigning various depths to various degrees of being out-of-focus but I doubt something usable would come out.

Answer (score 3):

No individual algorithm per say, but yes, it is possible.  It is very hard.  There are people working on this problem right now.  The algorithms involved are very challenging to write, they don't always work right, and any complete solution would require a large amount of processing power.  Any solution would be offline (instead of real time) at first.

3D perception isn't tied as closely to stereo optics as you might believe.  If you think you need two eyes to see 3D, then try walking around with an eyepatch on.  You'll do just fine.  There are a (small) number of programs out there, including some commercial software packages, that create 3D models from sets of 2D pictures without a stereo camera.  Some run online, constructing a more detailed model as more of it is seen.

Just thinking about it I can think of some problems you'd run into with movies in particular.  For example, I could imagine mattes getting rendered at an incorrect depth.  Videos with special effects from software like Apple Motion might end up with strange artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

On this year's [CES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_CES) show, [Toshiba](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba) presented the cell-TV display, and they claim that it is able to convert 2D tv-signals into 3D. I don't know if it produces a good result or what algorithm they are using, but if they are true there should be an algorithm for this.

But unfortunally, I don't know how it could be done.

Answer (score 2):

There are existing algorithms for extracting 3D shapes from 2D images, [here](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2009/0169113.html), or [here](http://make3d.stanford.edu/), for example.  You can extract shapes from each frame of video, and even use multiple frames to gain better understanding of shapes by detecting their motion.

However, odds are that the results will be of nowhere near the standard quality of content of a 3D movie.

Answer (score 2):

There was some research done on this at a place I once worked (although I wasn't involved with it at all). This paper, *[Automatic extraction of 3D models from an airborne video sequence](http://dspace.dsto.defence.gov.au/dspace/handle/1947/9122)* might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there will be an algorithm for emulating stereoscopic views, but it cannot be the same.

The reason is quite simple. In a 2D video is not only missing the depth information (which is not sufficient for getting a stereoscopic video), but it is missing the hidden surfaces which would be visible from another point of view.

Everyone could think that the depth information could be extrapoled from the available information, and this is true. But, the missing information cannot be so accurate for having a good stereoscopic effect.

Apart from that, I've heard about a system which coudl extract accurate 3D models from 8 (eight!) cameras pointing on the same target. It is so accurate to emulate also clothes movements correctly. However, this is done processing 8 (eight!) 2D videos. How it could be possible to achieve the same result with only one 2D video?

The achivement of the wanted result depends essentially by the information availability, and in this case (IMHO) there is not enought information. Althought, it could be possible to try to emulate stereoscopic effect from a 2D video, but essentially it needs an hard work, long processing and the consequence is low quality result respect an original stereospic video.

---

I would like to remember that the 3D view is generated by our brain. The eyes can capture only 2D images, and our brain, processing the two images can generate a depth view of the seen objects.